# Multi-processor usage in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I preparing now export procedure from SQL Server to third-party ERP system. It scans almost all tables from database scheme and creates XML for every product. Export is long enough, client wish make it faster. I realised that export procedure utilize only 1 CPU .

So i think if I run the same procedure several times with different parameters (different range of products), i can utilise all processors and it can be faster.

Questions

1. How i can do that using only SQL Server tools.
   One of possible solutions is using SSIS. Any other?
2. Number of processors can be vary. I can get processors count using `sys.dm_os_sys_info`. How dynamically start procedure several times dependable from processors quantity?

Comment: Is anything else using this server at the same time? If so, you might not want to tie up other processors.

Comment: This export will be done not on production server but on local one and only one time per every client database. But there are a lot of databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to bear in mind:

**1** - Are you SURE you are CPU bound and not IO bound?  In my experience, it's very rare to have the CPU be the bottleneck in a process and much more likely to have disk access speed restrictions.  You should do additional testing to avoid restructuring your entire process only to get a 2% speed increase because your hard drives can't keep up.

**2** - It could be as simple as checking your server-side parallelism setting.  Sometimes DBAs set this to 1 because it can mitigate issues with bad query plans, but normally there is limited benefit.

**3** - You can set the max degree of parallelism on a query using `OPTION (MAXDOP #)` where # is the number of parallel processes you want to allow.

Comment: 1. I check peformance counters - CPU is always 100%, but HD writes only about 30K per second - that is because all base in cached in memory  2. Yes, it has parallelizm=1 3. - MAXDOP only limits cores quantity, not widen it, isn`t it?

Comment: @Dalex - if perf counter indicates CPU is at 100% then what do you hope to gain my splitting into multiple batches?  If you are already CPU bound then you will just have 4 jobs running at 25% speed...

Comment: @Dalex - then I would look at MaxDOP to test.  It could be as simple as allowing more cores to be used by the query processor.

Comment: I test it. Unfortunately, MAXDOP will not gave others cores to be busy by query. In other words, result was the same.